# How to list all WMI classes having methods using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

Using VBScript, how can I list all WMI classes that have methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a [SELECT schema query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393278.aspx) to get a list of all classes in a namespace, and then check each class's [`Methods_.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393724.aspx):

```
strComputer  = "."
strNamespace = "root\cimv2"

Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\" & strNamespace)
Set colClasses = oWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM meta_class") 

For Each oClass in colClasses
  If oClass.Methods_.Count > 0 Then
    WScript.Echo oClass.Path_.Class
  End If
Next
```

You may want to limit the results to [*dynamic* and *static* classes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198938.aspx) only, like WMI Code Creator does. To do this, add an additional check for the corresponding class qualifiers.

```
...
For Each oClass in colClasses

  For Each oQualifier In oClass.Qualifiers_
    strQualName = LCase(oQualifier.Name)

    If strQualName = "dynamic" OR strQualName = "static" Then
      If oClass.Methods_.Count > 0 Then
        WScript.Echo oClass.Path_.Class
      End If
    End If

  Next
Next
```

I also suggest that you read the [WMI Scripting Primer: Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974592.aspx) article. It explains the WMI concepts and infrastructure in detail and with examples, and may already hold answers to your future questions. :)

Comment: It is also a good idea to check for the 'Implemented' qualifier presence on each method - there are methods that are present but not implemented (like 'SetPowerState' for instance).